# Working on a react drum machine project. My keydown eventlistener plays sound but it doesn't display its name on the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My keydown event listener plays sounds but it doesn't display the name of the sound, like it would if you were to press it manually with the mouse.

https://fccprojectdrummachine.netlify.app/

```
  function playSound(selector, id) {
    const audio = document.getElementById(selector);
    audio.play();
    setDisplayKey(id);
    console.log(audio);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const myListener = (event) => {
      playSound(event.key.toUpperCase());
      console.log(playSound(event.key.toUpperCase()));
    };

    if (enabled) {
      document.addEventListener("keydown", myListener);
    }
    if (!enabled) {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", myListener);
    }
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", myListener);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [enabled]);


  const sounds = [
    {
      keyCode: 81,
      key: "Q",
      id: "Heater-1",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3",
    },
    {
      keyCode: 87,
      key: "W",
      id: "Heater-2",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3",
    },
    {
      keyCode: 69,
      key: "E",
      id: "Heater-3",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3",
    },
    {
      keyCode: 65,
      key: "A",
      id: "Heater-4",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3",
    },
    {
      keyCode: 83,
      key: "S",
      id: "Clap",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3",
    },
    {
      keyCode: 68,
      key: "D",
      id: "Open-HH",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3",
    },
    {
      keyCode: 90,
      key: "Z",
      id: "Kick-n'-Hat",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3",
    },
    {
      keyCode: 88,
      key: "X",
      id: "Kick",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3",
    },
    {
      keyCode: 67,
      key: "C",
      id: "Closed-HH",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3",
    },
  ];
```

```
function Buttons({ playSound, sounds, enabled }) {
  return (
    <div className="btn-con">
      <div className="btns">
        {sounds.map((drumPad) => (
          <button
            disabled={!enabled}
            key={drumPad.id}
            onClick={() => {
              playSound(drumPad.key, drumPad.id);
            }}
            className="drum-pad"
            id={drumPad.id}
          >
            {drumPad.key}
            <audio
              className="clip"
              id={drumPad.key}
              src={drumPad.url}
              name={drumPad.id}
            ></audio>
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I pass the selector as property it display the letter of the key pressed like Q,W,E. I want it to display the name of the sound like HEATER-1, HEATER-2 or CLIP.

I've tried putting the `setDisplayKey` hook in the listener and passing different properties to no avail. And when I console log it, it just comes back undefined.

Comment: `playSound` takes two parameters. You pass one.

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention that in my problem. If I pass selector to setdisplaykey it displays letter of key press like Q,W,E, etc. I would like it to say the name of the sound like HEATER-1 or CLIP as it does when you press it manually.

Comment: How does it do it when you press it manually?

Comment: It should display Heater-1 or whatever the name of the sound that is clicked on with the mouse

Comment: ... You said "as it does when you press it manually". What makes it work when you "press it manually"?

Comment: The playsound function

Comment: I added the code for the buttons to the question as well.

Comment: You need to either associate the key with the ID and look it up in the key listener or add the key listener at the same time you do the mapping; there are a number of React-y keyboard handler components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing id to your `playSound` function in `event listeners`, that's the problem. If you update your `myListener` function in this way, it should work as you want

```
const myListener = (event) => {
      let song = sounds.find(
        (sound) => sound.key === event.key.toUpperCase()
      );
      playSound(event.key.toUpperCase(), song.id);
};
```

Here is the working codesandbox version of it https://codesandbox.io/embed/happy-ride-xjqfyu

Comment: You are welcome! Could you please choose my answer as accepted answer since it solved your problem? @GameSeven